# jQuery addClass to image after text was replaced with that image

Tags: jquery

i've tried a few things but i can't get this working , im using the following script to replace some text with images , but i need to add a class those images

```
   var $w = $( "#livescoring_summary" ),
        x = franchiseDatabase,
        y = 'fid_00',
        z = $( "#livescoring_summary" ).html();
for( i = 1; i<= 96; i++ ) {
   var j = (i < 10) ? y + '0' + i : y + i;
   z = z.replace( x[j].name, '<img src="' + x[j].icon + '" />' );
}
$w.html( z );
```

How can i add a class to the specific image

```
<img src="' + x[j].icon + '" />
```

I added this , which works , but some of the tables have other images in them that i don't want the class added too , so how can i specify the image i replaced instead of all images in the table

```
$("#livescoring_summary img").addClass( "franchiseicon" );
```

Comment: why can't you just add the wrapper div inside the `z.replace()`?

Comment: when i tried , would not function, unless i did it wrong..? example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you replace your text with images and add it to the dom, run this:

```
$("#livescoring_summary img").wrap("<div class='your_class'></div>" );
```

**EDIT**

To wrap only 'replaced' images, tag them with a class and wrap them. Something like this:

```
...
z = z.replace( x[j].name, '<img src="' + x[j].icon + '" class="replaced" />' );
...
$("#livescoring_summary img.replaced").wrap("<div class='your_class'></div>" );
```

Comment: @MShack I can help if you can setup a jsfiddle. The above should work. I suspect your html isn't setup properly. Does your document validate?